# Android move canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, move

I want to draw a big image on canvas, and after that I want to move that canvas so it shows me different part of this image. Without repainting it (or eventually repainting only the needed part). How is it done in android?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29) method. All you need to do is to specify horizontal and vertical distance to move your canvas. You can also scale, rotate or even apply custom matrix on canvas. [This tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) also might be helpful.